# Unable to add information to Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The goal of the following code is to save data in Cloud Firestore from a android device(api 24)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String NUM_KEY="num";
public static final String SMS_KEY="sms";
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private DocumentReference mDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("android/websms");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void saveSMS(View view){
    EditText num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num);
    EditText sms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg);
    String quotenum = num.getText().toString();
    String quotesms =  sms.getText().toString();
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Map<String,Object> dataToSave = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    dataToSave.put(NUM_KEY,quotenum);
    dataToSave.put(SMS_KEY,quotesms);
        mDocRef.set(dataToSave).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Document has been saved");
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG,"Document was not saved",e);
            }
        });

}
```

I'm following some Firestore tutorials on youtube and it seems to be a little bit outdated because when I'm running it on my android device I get the following error on the console

04-17 02:09:50.718 2600-2712/com.example.joao.websms1 E/art: The String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0

Thank you in advance to anyone willing to help.

Comment: Are you sure that error message is coming from your app?  I don't see how that can happen here. The message comes from deep down in native Android code under very special circumstances.

Comment: I assume it comes from the code because it only pops when i press the button on the application. could it be something in the layout? I really have no clue of whats going on...

Comment: Are you using some obscure foreign Android device?  Does this happen in a modern emulator?

Comment: i'm using a regular huawei p10 lite... and i havent tried it on a emulator. i havent used the android virtual devices cuz they are kinda buggy on my computer

Comment: Same thing with me. Did you find a fix? @JoãoVieira

Answer (score 0):

¿Have u tried using the method push?

```
mDocRef.push(dataToSave).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Document has been saved");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG,"Document was not saved",e);
        }
    });
```

Comment: cant use it...
cannot resolve method 'push(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>)

Comment: I am looking your code more detailed and i can´t find the moment when the button make the click listener...

Comment: yes, somewhy the error only appears when i click the button on the app and i've tried to add the onclick method and it also doesnt work

Comment: This question is talking about Firestore, not Realtime Database.  There is no push operation in Firestore.