# Unable to add data to document in firestore (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add data to a document to Firebase Firestore. I've added a collection named `users` to it. Also the read/write permissions are open for now. I'm following [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data). And I'm not able to add data to document.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
private void getNewUserSnapShot() {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    Log.d(TAG, "getNewUserSnapShot: user_uid: " + user.getUid());
    DocumentReference user_doc_ref = db.collection("users").document();

    Log.d(TAG, "getNewUserSnapShot: document ref: " + user_doc_ref.getId());

    Map<String, Object> user_data = new HashMap<>();
    user_data.put("name", user.getDisplayName());
    user_data.put("email", user.getEmail());
    user_data.put("profile_url", user.getPhotoUrl());

    Log.d(TAG, "getNewUserSnapShot: user_data: " + user_data.toString());

    user_doc_ref
            .set(user_data)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, task.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "getNewUserSnapShot: success");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "getNewUserSnapShot: failed");
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

In Logs I see only these (neither the log for failure nor for success):

```
2020-03-04 19:48:47.489 30744-30744/com.example.expenditure D/LoginActivity: getNewUserSnapShot: user_uid: iXOzfju6kORnhuUND8zFCPTzxY93
2020-03-04 19:48:47.499 30744-30744/com.example.expenditure D/LoginActivity: getNewUserSnapShot: document ref: 7AluPzcYMLzDKLh8YtBt
2020-03-04 19:48:47.499 30744-30744/com.example.expenditure D/LoginActivity: getNewUserSnapShot: user_data: {profile_url=https://someurl/security/reasons, name=Nikhil Wagh, email=null}
```

And when I see firebase console, I can't find the document with ID `7AluPzcYMLzDKLh8YtBt`, according to logs which should have been created.

There is a similar question: [Unable to add information to Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868406/unable-to-add-information-to-cloud-firestore) But it doesn't have right answers.

Can someone help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would you mind tagging this question with the language you're working in?

Comment: So you say that `user.getUid()` is different than the actual document id that is added in the database? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: No @AlexMamo, `user.getUid()` has nothing to do with what has to be added, It was just to show `user` is not null. The problem is nothing is added to the database. In the logs too, I couldn't find anything.

Comment: can you add an image of your database structure?

Comment: Image like screenshot my database? Or just the structure of how it should be? @StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was `user.getPhotoUrl()` returns `url`, but Firestore doesn't support urls. The url needs to be casted as a string, and then it works.

**Cast your urls to string before adding data to Firestore.**

Comment: It should be a bug. There was no error or anything when trying to add a url. There should be something in logs.